# curl execute url with parameters using get method

Tags: php, curl, get

I an trying to execute a url with parameters in order to insert the parameters to a website that can receive them only by `GET` method.

If I set the form method to `GET` the params enter the system.

Now, I want to do some things after the data is inserted.
I am trying ti use curl in order to execute the url.

This is the code:

```
<?php

$firstname = 'dav';
$lastname = 'sev';
$cellular = '321321321';
$mail = 'aaa@aaa.aaa';
$department = '';
$bagrut = 1;
$campid = 7;
$sourceid = 56;
$pirsumi = 0;


echo  $firstname  .' '. $lastname .' '. $cellular .' '.  $mail .' '.  $department .' '.  $bagrut .' '.  $campid .' '.   $sourceid  .' '.  $pirsumi;
$values = array(
    'FIRSTNAME' =>$firstname,
    'LASTNAME' => $lastname,
    'CELLULAR' => $cellular,
    'EMAIL' => $mail,
    'DEPARTMENT' => $department,
    'BAGRUT_ZAKAI' => $bagrut,
    'CAMPAIGNID' => $campid,
    'SOURCEID' => $sourceid,
    'SEND_MAIL_PIRSUMI' => $pirsumi

);


    $qry_str = http_build_query($values);
    $callurl = curl_init();
    $url = 'http://someurl.com?' . $qry_str;

    curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_exec($callurl);

    curl_close($callurl);

    echo $url;

?>
```

the url output is correct but this is the result I receive in the page

```
Found
The document has moved.

http://someurl.com?FIRSTNAME=dav&LASTNAME=sev&CELLULAR=321321321&EMAIL=aaa%40aaa.aaa&DEPARTMENT=&BAGRUT_ZAKAI=1&CAMPAIGNID=7&SOURCEID=56&SEND_MAIL_PIRSUMI=0
```

1. Where is this text coming from?
   `Found
   The document has moved.`
2. What is wrong with my code?
3. Are there alternative ways to so this action?

Thanks

Comment: The requested URL returns a [http 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) status code (saying that the URL has been moved). Add a `curl_setopt($callurl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true):` to make your call automatically follow redirects.

Comment: Thank you, I added the line after this line: `curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);` now I don't get 302 error. In the `Network` tab in chrome I see status code: 200. I dont understand why the data in not inserted to the website. If I copy the `$url` variable to the url line in the browser the data is inserted.

Comment: Is the query string passed correctly with the redirect? If you can see what URL it redirects to, you could change your code to go to that URL directly. Is the URL under your control? Usually, you don't insert data using GET, but rather POST. GET is used for retrieving data while POST/PUT/DELETE is for insert, update and delete data

Comment: Thank you. from what I see after printing the `$url` var the query string is correct, if I copy it to the url line the data is received by the website. the url is not under my control. I am aware of the `GET` usages but thank you for the explanation,  How can I debug it?